# CCSprite slows down performance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am making an app for the iPhone using cocos2d for the graphics and I added 4 pictures to my project that I wanted to overlay to use as the background.  I then added them to the app by making them CCSprites like this...

```
    background.sun = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"SunLayer.png"];
    [self addChild:background.sun z:-1];

    background.mountain = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"MountainLayer.png"];
    [self addChild:background.mountain z:-1];

    background.tree = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"TreeLayer.png"];
    [self addChild:background.tree z:-1];

    background.hill = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"HillLayer.png"];
    [self addChild:background.hill z:-1];


    background.hill.position = ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2);
    background.sun.position = ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2);
    background.mountain.position = ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2);
    background.tree.position = ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2);
```

This brought my frame rate down to 30! from 60!! how can I maintain a good frame rate but add these sprites! thankyou

Comment: This on it's own shouldn't lower the frame rate. Are you only calling this code once? Are these images particularly large?

Comment: These images all take up the whole screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With large images, you will significantly improve frame rate if you add them to a CCSpriteBatchNode rather than individually, as you are. This way the CPU will only make one call to the drawing engine, rather than individual calls for each image. CCSpriteBatchNode has been shown in testing to have most benefits when applied towards large images, such as background images.

Comment: Batch processing is especially useful with many sprites, not large ones.

Comment: Stephen Itterheim (spelling?) did a rather robust series of tests on performance as it related to batch nodes; check his site. he was surprised to discover that the most significant benefits comes primarily from working with large images. It makes sense; the larger the image, the greater the drawing resources. by removing the drawing for several large images and consolidating into one, the benefits will be seen above the benefits for smaller images; just like the problems that arise from using large images are more significant than the issues that typically result from using small images.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are all adding them at the same z, why not do this in photoshop or equivalent and add a single texture ? Do you need to fade or otherwise process any one of theses textures individually ?

Also, i find often that the FPS on simulator has no resemblance to what I will be getting on the device(s) proper. When you suspect a performance issue, i would advise you to rapidly do a quick test on device to evaluate if the issue is real or not.

Comment: Great thought! but I need to move each sprite differently.  It is a jumping game like doodle jump and as the player rises each layer slowly goes down but the foreground will be going down much faster then the mountains in the way back.

Comment: I think you are trying to implement a parallax. You can use CCParallaxNode for this. Just add your CCSprites to CCParallaxNode with coefficients, instead of self (CCLayer).

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of the big image size.

I had exactly the same problem. I had 4 images of 960x640. While 3 of them is mostly transparent, I just resized their canvas to 960x640 for positioning them easily at the center.

And this gave me shitty 25fps drop. 35fps instead of 60.

I cropped the 3 images to their content bounds, and made them about 960x50. 
And it works like a charm, 60fps again.

Comment: Part of my images are transparent also, so I will try cropping them! However, the majority is colored so I could not see it improving the performance greatly.

Comment: I cropped and it improved the performence slightly I'm bouncing around 45 now :) thanks would love to hear some more ideas though

Comment: Using batch sprites, and atlases can help improving performance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Cocos2d in a while, but have you tried setting the position before adding the sprite to the layer? Also are you sure your only adding them once when you initialize? Also what are the sizes of the images?

Comment: I just tried setting the position before adding the sprite to the layer and it changed nothing.  The code shown above is in the INIT method so it is only executed once.  And all 4 images are 320x480

Answer (score 0):

This is because of two factors combined:

a) Transparency is **very expensive** with the PowerVR GPU

b) Large pictures even more